# SQL Broker: Async procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, service-broker

I have read this great Remus Rusanu's article 
http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

How to implement this idea:

I have a big main table, user can mark 'as delete' records there (set field to 1)
I cannot use SQL Jobs because customers can use SQLExpress.

The idea is: when user 'delete' or 'undelete' records in big table need to send message to a queue.
An activation proc 'fire and forget' proc to execute real Delete statement for marked records in the main table - all or parts, it depends.

But need maximally to avoid blocking.... That's why the question:

How to execute real deletion when SQL Server has a lowest loading? or when database has a lowest activity?
How to detect these 'Low database loading' moments in the async proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to lync Service Broker activation directly to workload and only activate during 'low activity'.

> I cannot use SQL Jobs because customers can use SQLExpress

While is true that SQL Server Express Edition lacks SQL Agent scheduling, there are work arounds using Service Broker [conversation timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx). See [Scheduling Jobs in SQL Server Express](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express) (and [part 2](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express-2)).